# Trying to use ProbabilityDistribution for custom distribution - Getting errors/warnings I don't understand

Tags: probability-or-statistics, warning-messages, distributions

I have this custom distribution that I want to use in Mathematica, but there
appears to be some sort of problem I don't understand.

Also, when I compute the mean for the custom distribution via
Mathematica, I get 2.74084, while the correct answer is 1.577661

Can someone help me? Thanks...

```
PvA[v_, A_] := (A^v*Exp[-A])/Factorial[v];
SumF[P_, i_, A_] := Sum[P[[vv + 1]]*PvA[i - vv + 1, A], {vv, 2, i}];
Pr[Aval_, k_] := Module[{A = Aval, P = Table[0, {k + 1}]},
   P[[1]] = 1 - A;
   P[[2]] = (1 - A)*(Exp[A] - 1);
   For[i = 2, i <= k, i++, 
    P[[i + 1]] = (1/
        PvA[0, A])*(P[[i]] - (P[[1]] + P[[2]])*PvA[i - 1, A] - 
        SumF[P, i - 1, A])];
   Last[P]];
```

```
α = 0.5;
```

```
X = ProbabilityDistribution[((Pr[α, -1 + x]/
      Sum[Pr[α, j], {j, 0, -1 + x}]) - (Pr[α, x]/
      Sum[Pr[α, j], {j, 0, x}])), {x, 1, 30}]
```

```
Table::iterb: Iterator {x} does not have appropriate bounds.

Table::iterb: Iterator {x} does not have appropriate bounds.

Last::nolast: {} has zero length and no last element.

Table::iterb: Iterator {1+j} does not have appropriate bounds.

General::stop: Further output of Table::iterb will be suppressed during this calculation.

Last::nolast: {} has zero length and no last element.

Last::nolast: {} has zero length and no last element.

General::stop: Further output of Last::nolast will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

```
In[1893]:= N[Mean[X]]

Out[1893]= 2.74084
```

```
Sum[x*((Pr[α, -1 + x]/
      Sum[Pr[α, j], {j, 0, -1 + x}]) - (Pr[α, x]/
      Sum[Pr[α, j], {j, 0, x}])), {x, 1, 30}]
```

```
1.57661
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

PvA[v_, A_] := (A^v*Exp[-A])/Factorial[v];

SumF[P_, i_, A_] := Sum[P[[vv + 1]]*PvA[i - vv + 1, A], {vv, 2, i}];
```

You need to keep `Pr` from evaluating unless `k` has an integer value

```
Pr[Aval_, k_Integer] := 
  Module[{A = Aval, P = Table[0, {k + 1}]}, P[[1]] = 1 - A;
   P[[2]] = (1 - A)*(Exp[A] - 1);
   For[i = 2, i <= k, i++, 
    P[[i + 1]] = (1/PvA[0, A])*(P[[i]] - (P[[1]] + P[[2]])*PvA[i - 1, A] - 
        SumF[P, i - 1, A])];
   Last[P]];

α = 0.5;
```

`X` is a discrete distribution so you must specify a step size

```
X = ProbabilityDistribution[((Pr[α, -1 + x]/
      Sum[Pr[α, j], {j, 0, -1 + x}]) - (Pr[α, x]/
      Sum[Pr[α, j], {j, 0, x}])), {x, 1, 30, 1}]
```

[image]

```
Mean[X]

(* 1.57661 *)
```